# How can caller know if exception was raised during execution of callee in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

```
def foo():
   try:
      do_something()
   except:
      raise
      handle exception

def bar():
   try:
      foo()
   except:
      print 'Error occurred in foo()'
```

How will `bar` come to know that `foo` has raised an exception ?

Also , the output of below code is different if :

```
def foo():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except Exception:
        return  'Caught in foo'

try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except Exception:
    print 'Caught in main'
```

`OUTPUT` : FOOO \n Caught in foo

```
try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except Exception:
    print 'Caught in main'


def foo():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except Exception:
        return  'Caught in foo'
```

`OUTPUT` : FOOO \n Caught in main

Why is the output different in both cases ?

Comment: Let me guess... by exception propagation? Of course if exception in foo escapes it. If you mean how interpreter does it - stack unwinds until `try` or top level is reached.

Comment: All we have in python (at the level of interpreter not compiler) is about run time,and in this case when python runs the `bar` function and arrive to `foo` it execute the foo and if it raise an exception python will reports it.

Comment: Btw in the case when foo is defined after try you get `NameError` because `foo` is undefined at that point. That's why output is different.

Comment: When you catch a exception you can throw an other exeption what allows you to manage where the exception was thrown. e.g you can make an exceptionclass `fooException` and throw that one when foo has thrown an Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you print exception message when you do exception handling

when you execute this code

```
try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except Exception, err:
    print 'Caught in main: {}'.format(err)


def foo():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except Exception, err:
        return  'Caught in foo: {}'.format(err)
```

you get:

```
FOOO
Caught in main: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Because foo method was not interpreted yet

But when you do:

```
def foo():

    try:
        print 1/0
    except Exception , err:
        return  'Caught in foo: {}'.format(err)

try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except Exception , err:
    print 'Caught in main: {}'.format(err)
```

You get:

```
FOOO
Caught in foo: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Because foo is already known by the interpreter, and the return message of the exception is printed by your line:

```
print foo()
```

So the main exception is not reached in this case.

Comment: None of your "exception handlers" handle diddly-squat; printing an error is not "handling". It would be best to dispose of the except blocks and let useful errors propagate up. Also never use `except Exception` unless you think catching KeyboardInterrupt is a great idea (it isn't).

Comment: @msw the initial question was for him to understand the difference of responding behavior, this is not coding, but clarification.

Comment: "I suggest you print exception message when you do exception handling" right up there at the top. To answer the question "How can caller know if exception was raised during execution of callee in Python" is not answered by swallowing errors or printing something. The way for a caller to know if an exception was raised by its callee is to **not** discard the exception in the callee and let the caller catch it if and only if it can actually handle it (or catch and re-raise if it can't be handled there).